# Is there any risk to building URLs manually?

Tags: node.js, path

In node.js, it's possible to create paths to files using the standard `path` lib, e.g.:

```
const path = require('path');
const myPath = path.join('directory', 'file');
```

Is there any risk to building paths manually instead?  For instance:

```
const myPath = 'directory/file';
```

I'm guessing it should be fine because:

- There's nothing specifically [in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) about this.
- I've never used an OS (even Windows) that doesn't accept `/` as a path separator.

Answer (score 0):

When your entire path is static, as in your `myPath = 'directory/file'` example, there is no distinct advantage that I know of.

However, if you're constructing a path dynamically, `path.join` and the like are essential.

One important reason is that, unlike string concatenation, `path.join` et al will prevent unexpected behavior when one of the arguments is not a string.

In JavaScript, bugs related to values being `undefined` are common. Suppose you have some code in your app that redirects users to their profile after login:

```
if (success) {
  res.redirect(`/users/${params.username}`);
}
```

Looks great, right? Not so fast. It turns out that the username property is actually `params.userName`, so you're redirecting every user to `/users/undefined`. No error is thrown, and your unit tests don't check the redirect URL, so this bug gets deployed.

If you had done this instead:

```
res.redirect(path.join('/users', params.username));
```

...it would have thrown an ArgumentError error immediately, your unit tests would have failed, and the bug would never have been deployed.

Is this a naïve example? Yes. Would it be easy to check for `undefined`? Yes. But when you make a habit of using `path.join` you don't have to worry about that. You know, at the very least, that you'll never accidentally end up with an `undefined` or `null` or `123` in your path.

It's even more important on the server side. Suppose you have an app that handles file uploads and you want a user's uploads to go into a directory with their username for its name:

```
fs.mkdir(`images/${params.username}`, err => {
  if (err) { throw new Error('Oops!'); }
  fs.writeFile(`images/${params.username}/${params.filename}`, params.filedata, /* ... */);
});
```

Now you have every user's uploads being written to `images/undefined`. It could be a long time (in business terms) before someone notices this bug.

Answer (score -1):

Not in my point of view, I'm actually using this a lot once I'm heavy user of `babel` to use import.